# Merging s-maxage and max-age

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, mod-expires

I currently have this in my htaccess.

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
  Header set Cache-Control 's-maxage=604800'
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
  ExpiresActive On
  ExpiresByType text/html A86400
</IfModule>
```

HTTP headers will show as...

```
Cache-Control: s-maxage=604800
Cache-Control: max-age=86400
Expires: Wed, 18 Dec 2013 03:51:18 GMT
```

How do I merge s-maxage and max-age so that it will show as:

```
Cache-Control: max-age=86400, s-maxage=604800
```

I've tried using Header set, append, merge and add but nothing works. It seems that ExpiresActive On will automatically include Cache-Control: max-age to the headers.

Answer (score 2):

According to the [manual](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_headers.html), ordering is important. Try re-ordering the two directives and using `merge` to prevent any duplicates:

```
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
  ExpiresActive On
  ExpiresByType text/html A86400
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
  Header merge Cache-Control 's-maxage=604800'
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Followed your suggestion and still the same thing except that it shows s-maxage first followed by max-age at the next line.

Comment: It works for me on Apache Apache/2.4.4 - which version of Apache are you running? Are you sure your browser isn't caching the response?

Comment: Oh, my server is running LiteSpeed Enterprise... And I use "Fetch as Google" from my Google Webmaster account to check the headers.

Comment: According to this http://www.litespeedtech.com/docs/webserver/config/general#htaccess you can't have `IfModule` directives in your htaccess - you'll have to  read up on their documentation or ask their support team.

Comment: You can check the headers in Chrome or Firefox using their developer tools: hit F12 to open the dev tools, click on the Network tab and refresh, then you can click on a request to view the headers.

Answer (score 0):

If you use `Header edit` you can add the s-maxage header depending on the max-age header:

```
ExpiresByType text/html A86400
ExpiresByType text/xml A86401

Header edit Cache-Control ^(max-age=86400)$ "$1; s-maxage=604800"
```

Result: s-maxage is only added for text/html

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer is that there may not be an easy way to join your two headers, but it doesn't actually matter. Semantically there is no difference between this form:

```
Cache-Control: s-maxage=604800
Cache-Control: max-age=86400
```

and this form:

```
Cache-Control: s-maxage=604800, max-age=86400
```

[RFC 7234 § 5.2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7234#section-5.2) defines the `Cache-Control` header field value as a list of directives defined in a specific form:

> ```
> Cache-Control   = 1#cache-directive
>
> cache-directive = token [ "=" ( token / quoted-string ) ]
> ```

That form is subject to this HTTP rule from [RFC 2616 § 4.2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-4.2):

> Multiple message-header fields with the same field-name MAY be present in a message if and only if the entire field-value for that header field is defined as a comma-separated list [i.e., `#(values)`]. It MUST be possible to combine the multiple header fields into one "field-name: field-value" pair, without changing the semantics of the message, by appending each subsequent field-value to the first, each separated by a comma. The order in which header fields with the same field-name are received is therefore significant to the interpretation of the combined field value, and thus a proxy MUST NOT change the order of these field values when a message is forwarded.

*(Note that the `#(values)` grammar is defined in [§ 2.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-2.1))*

Therefore, if a client is treating those two varieties differently, it is in violation of HTTP/1.1.

In fact, there is a chance that what you are seeing as two headers is actually being sent to the client as a single conjoined header line, but your viewer or output is keeping the directives split into two for display.